# How can I change, in tmux, the default begin-selection key?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tmux

I am trying to change the default way to copy and paste in `tmux` (I'm on ver `2.1` for Ubuntu).

If I press the *Prefix* key combination `Ctrl+b` then hit `[` then Ctrl+Space it works but I want to change C+Space with something else.

The usual modification in .tmux.conf doesn't work, which is:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection
```

The error is very cryptic, something like: **Error is usage send-keys [-lRM] [-t target-pane] key...**

Answer (score 1):

Your tmux is too old for `-T` and `send -X` so you can either upgrade or use the old form, IIRC something like:

```
bind -temacs-copy v begin-selection
```